# После монтирования раздела fat32 в /home имена файлом и папок на русском языке отображаются некорректно

Tags: linux, кодировка, fedora, mount, fat32

[image: вот чего удалось добиться прочитав форум]

В общем, смонтировал диск командой mount `/dev/sda5 /home/.../.../`, вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить кодировку текста?

Comment: [yandex://mount+fat+chaset](https://www.yandex.ru/search/?text=mount%20fat%20charset) → [первая ссылка](https://archlinux.org.ru/forum/topic/13230/)

Comment: Ну ты тут не первый день. Так сложно выкладывать текст НЕ картинкой?

Comment: Выкладываю как могу вносите изменения, все поправим , система должна работать

Comment: Монтировать fat32 в /home — определённо плохая идея

Comment: В роде пока все работает . А что не так ?

Comment: @andreymal или ты о правах что не переносятся на фат 32 ? ну так мне не страшно у меня ничего не хранится администраторского в хоме

Comment: @Gybernaty то что в хоме действительно неважно, а вот права самого́ хоме — это очень даже страшно

Comment: ближе к материи, какой по вашему сценарий атаки становится актуален из за того что я примонтировал в хоме фат32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mount -t vfat /dev/sda5 /home/gy/CISTERN/ -o iocharset=utf8,codepage=866
вот эта команда всё смонтировала как надо , а для автоматизации в файл /etc/fstab добавил вот такую строку разделённую табуляцими : UUID="2795-CA33"    /home/gy/CISTERN    vfat    auto,uid=gy,gid=gy,umask=0077,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866